# Repast: plot the KPI of each single agent

Tags: repast-simphony

Instead of plot the aggregated average of the entire agent set (retailers & distributors), I want to explicitly plot the KPI of each single agent(e.g. retailer-1, retailer-2....). I read the non-aggregate plotting method but it did not work well.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you should need to create the disaggregated data collection is that each agent has a unique ID. A toString() method that provides that should suffice. Let us know if this was the issue.

Comment: thanks. but how to plot the different class agents together in one chart? the data set can only be created in one class.

Comment: You could have them all implement a common interface that provides a getKPI method.